# Should I require explicitly all dependencies in every file?

Tags: ruby, dependencies, require, modularity

I am asking this for Ruby, but I guess this principle can be applied to every project with multiple files. Say I have a main file e.g. `application` that requires some other modules `model1` and `model2`. Both those modules need the `common` module. I've seen many Ruby projects that would require `common` in `application` and *not* in `model1` and `model2`. While this works if you always use `application` directly, if you require one of the modules from elsewhere, you get a `NameError`. So maybe this impacts the modularity of the project? Should I always prefer requiring explicitly all the dependencies from every file? (By not making any assumption about *where* the file is required from)

Comment: Somewhat related example of a bug caused by missing dependencies: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6896883/active-merchant-uninitialized-constant-activesupportxmlmini-rexmlstringio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would always require all dependecies if a module is designed to be loaded from different applications. If `model1`is only an application specific element, you don't need to load already loaded modules.

But it would take  a look, what's really needed. 
Does `model1` and `model2` need `common` or does require the mainfile.rb? (I don't think, that's the case in your specific case) Sometimes you don't need to load all requirements, if one of your requirements (let's call it main-requirment) already loads the other (sub-)requirements.

Answer (score 1):

I place the `require`s in the very files that are using the things that are being `require`d.  This sections off your code into portable modules.  You can move files among directories/namespaces, and you can pluck parts out and put them into other repositories/projects, or turn them into gems.  The practice of `require`ing where needed also makes your code more communicative, and therefore easier to understand.  A reader is better-informed early on about the area of responsibility of the code in the file.

By putting the `require`s up in some upper- or top-level file, you are embedding the coupling of the higher-level file with the lower-level one.  The higher-level file acquires knowledge about what the lower-level file does and needs.  You also obscure where dependencies are actually used.  This makes cleanup more challenging, should you desire to remove unused dependencies.  You can't tell as easily where and how a given dependency is used.  If `require`s are put where they are used, then you can remove a `require` from a given file when you remove the dependency usage from that file, and if it happens to be `require`d in another file, your app will not break because of the removal.  If you put `require` in the higher-level file, there is risk that a developer can remove the usage from one file, and then think that the dependency is no longer used, and remove the `require` from the higher-level file, thereby breaking the code in other files that use it.